# WordPress Plugin and MagicQuotes

Tags: php, wordpress

I've create a Quizz Plugin for Wordpress. The server have the Magic Quotes enabled.

But, in the form admin of my plugin, when I send a value (POST or GET) with a quote ('), I get something like this :

```
My value with \'quote\' and accents : éééé
```

So, I add a stripslashes($_POST["my_value"]) but when I do that, the accent are transform in unreadable characteres like ©©

How can I do for insert in my plugin table, the good value as :

```
My value with 'quote' and accents : éééé
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use the WP function stripslashes :

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep
```

That's do the trick.